# Pipenv vs setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pipenv

I am trying to migrate to `pipenv`. I traditionally used `setup.py` with `pip` and did `pip install -e .` to install the module as a package, so that I can achieve stuff like `from myproject.xyz.abc import myClass` from anywhere within the project.

How do I achieve the similar effect with `pipenv` and get rid of the `setup.py`?

Note: I am using `python 2.7`.

Comment: does not `pipenv install -e .` works?

Comment: `pipenv` is not a replacement for `distutils`.

Comment: @georgexsh It wasnt working. As a workaround, I created a fake `setup.py` without any dependencies or anything, and went away with `pip install -e .`. This allowed me to do package imports.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Update:

pipenv 9.0.0 has been [released](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/), which should allow you to use `pipenv install -e .` as expected.

### Original answer:

`pipenv install -e` is buggy and has been [fixed in master](https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv/issues/1104#issuecomment-346020829) ([pull request](https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv/pull/1095/files)). It will be available in the next release, sometime after Thanksgiving.

Temporary workaround for now is:

```
pipenv shell
pip install -e .
```

After the release, you should be able to run `pipenv install -e .` similar to what you'd expect with `pip`.

Comment: Yeah..thats what I observed during the couple of last days. It seems `pipenv` is still going through many changes.

Answer (score 20):

**UPDATE: 5 mar 2019:** Since pip version 19.03 you can omit setup.py for your packages and use `pyproject.toml` and `[build-system]` (not supporting installation in the editable mode (in this case you still need setup.py)

**UPDATE: 12 jun 2018:** One more similar tool https://github.com/takluyver/flit . There is a big future behind `poetry` and `flit`. Hope they will merge forces and we'll have all-in-one comfortable packages and app management, like, rust `cargo` for example

---

**UPDATE: 19 Apr 2018:** There is a similar tool, which may handle all packaging management at once, without the need of setup.py. This is https://github.com/sdispater/poetry

---

**UPDATE: 11 Apr 2018:**
The author of Pipenv describes the problem here: http://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipfile-vs-setup-py

---

If you run `pipenv install -e .` in a package which has no setup.py, then you'll get:

```
$ pipenv install -e .              
Directory '.' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
```

So you need `setup.py` anyway for such case.

It is important to understand the concept behind applications and packages. This information could be useful https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/

If you're building an application, then `pipenv` is the only thing you need.

However, if you're building a package, then you have to have `setup.py` anyway, in order to allow pip or pipenv install of it (maybe in the editable mode as well).

The answer by the author of the `pipenv` is here: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1161#issuecomment-349972287

Thus, `pipenv vs setup.py` is a wrong formulation. They can't be against each other. Rather support each other, or exclude each other.

We may have to find a way how to use them both, without duplicating things.

When you're building a package, you may still use pipenv, but this leads to duplicate things (requiremets in setup.py and Pipfile). I am using the following approach to address this:

```
import pathlib
import subprocess

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install
from setuptools.command.develop import develop


__requires__ = ['pipenv']

packages = find_packages(exclude=['tests'])
base_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

pipenv_command = ['pipenv', 'install', '--deploy', '--system']
pipenv_command_dev = ['pipenv', 'install', '--dev', '--deploy', '--system']

class PostDevelopCommand(develop):
    """Post-installation for development mode."""
    def run(self):
        subprocess.check_call(pipenv_command_dev)
        develop.run(self)

class PostInstallCommand(install):
    """Post-installation for installation mode."""
    def run(self):
        subprocess.check_call(pipenv_command)
        install.run(self)


with open(base_dir / 'README.md', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='dll_api',
    use_scm_version = True,
    long_description='\n' + long_description,
    packages=packages,
    setup_requires=['setuptools_scm'],
    cmdclass={
        'develop': PostDevelopCommand,
        'install': PostInstallCommand,
    },
)
```

Now you have the following:

```
$ python setup.py install
running install
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (e05404)…
```

Note `pipenv` should be installed before!

This is not a clean way to solve the problem, however, do the job.

Comment: @khan Hi, pls check it out. It seems now we have much more information on this

Comment: The author of `pipenv` mentioned here: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1161#issuecomment-349972287, that `pipenv` is for `applications` while `setup.py` is for `packages`. How do you distinguish `packages` vs `apps` vs `distribution` vs `libraries` in the python ecosystem?

Comment: It seems that in the python ecosystem, because of OO nature of how applications are built, one a package depends on multiple modules, a module depends on multiple classes. So there are always dependencies. Just like a `class` is a level above a `function`, a `module` is a level above `class`, a `package` is a level above `module`, is a `app` a level` above a `package`?

Comment: As somebody who only occasionally dips into the Python ecosystem, the packaging and distribution pieces are **absolute nightmares**. So much for _There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it._ - I can't even figure out how to run scripts in `bin/` with Python code from a different package directory...

Comment: @ArtemZhukov Using `pipenv` in `setup.py` is an interesting approach, but then the package requires `pipenv` even though it doesn't really require `pipenv`. Maybe a better approach would be for `setup.py` to read the `Pipfile` and populate `install_requires` and `extras_require` dynamically.

Comment: @Terrabits I believe something similar will be solved when pip will retire setup.py and switch to pyproject .toml

Comment: @alpha_989: A __module__ is a file with extension '.py' with python code in it. A __package__ is a folder that contains a  `__init__.py` file and python modules. A __distribution__ is an archive with packages or modules + metadata. A __library__ is a distribution intended to be used by other libraries or applications. An __application__ is one or more python packages or modules intended to be used by an user (instead of a library) and that not necessarily is a distribution.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, `pipenv` replaces `pip` but you will still need a `setup.py`.

Assuming your directory is structured like this:

```
dir_a/              <-- This will be your pipenv root dir and your package root dir.
    setup.py
    dir_b/
        __init__.py
        somefile.py
        otherfile.py
```

Then you can initiate a Python 3 environment and install your package using:

```
$> cd dir_a
$> pipenv --python 3
$> pipenv shell
$> pipenv install -e .
```

You can verify that the package has been installed using `cat Pipfile` or `pipenv graph`.

However, **if your package root directory is not the same as your pipenv root directory then `pipenv install -e .` will fail** with a mysterious error message:

> Error parsing requirement . -- are you sure it is installable?

In this case, you should call `pipenv install -e` from the pipenv root directory and give the path to the root directory of the package.  For example, with this file structure:

```
dir_z/              <-- This will be your pipenv root dir.
    something.py
    empty_dir/
    dir_a/          <-- This is your package root dir.
        setup.py
        dir_b/
            __init__.py
            somefile.py
            otherfile.py
```

You would use:

```
$> cd dir_z
$> pipenv --python 3
$> pipenv shell
$> pipenv install -e dir_a/
```

As another user mentioned, using `pip install -e .` does install the package into the virtual environment from `dir_a` in this scenario.  However, at least for me, it doesn't update the `Pipfile` so is not of much use.